# How can I position my actionbar list navigation on the right side?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

[image]

This image demonstrats what I need to do. I need the dropdown menu to always stay on the left next to the overflow menu icon

How can i do this?

**My styles.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- Variation on the Holo Light theme that styles the Action Bar -->
    <style name="Theme.AndroidDevelopers" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">
        <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/ad_selectable_background</item>
        <item name="actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/ad_selectable_background</item>
        <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/MyPopupMenu</item>
        <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/MyPopupMenu</item>
        <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/MyDropDownListView</item>
        <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/MyDropDownListView</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabStyle</item>
        <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabStyle</item>
        <item name="android:actionDropDownStyle">@style/MyDropDownNav</item>
        <item name="actionDropDownStyle">@style/MyDropDownNav</item>
        <item name="android:listChoiceIndicatorMultiple">@drawable/ad_btn_check_holo_light</item>
        <item name="android:listChoiceIndicatorSingle">@drawable/ad_btn_radio_holo_light</item>

        <!-- <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/MyOverflowButton</item> -->
    </style>

    <!-- style the overflow menu -->
    <style name="MyPopupMenu" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.PopupMenu">
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/ad_menu_dropdown_panel_holo_light</item>
    </style>

    <!-- style the items within the overflow menu -->
    <style name="MyDropDownListView" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ListView.DropDown">
        <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/ad_selectable_background</item>
    </style>

    <!-- style for the tabs -->
    <style name="MyActionBarTabStyle" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.TabBar">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_tab_bg</item>
    </style>

    <!-- style the list navigation -->
    <style name="MyDropDownNav" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/ad_spinner_background_holo_light</item>
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/ad_menu_dropdown_panel_holo_light</item>
        <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/ad_selectable_background</item>

    </style>

    <!--
         the following can be used to style the overflow menu button
         only do this if you have an *extremely* good reason to!!


    -->
    <!--
    <style name="MyOverflowButton" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionButton.Overflow">
        <item name="android:src">@drawable/ic_menu_view</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/action_button_background</item>
    </style>


    -->

  <style name="customRatingBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.RatingBar">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable" >@drawable/custom_ratingbar</item>
    <item name="android:indeterminateDrawable">@drawable/money_off</item>
     <item name="android:minHeight">10dip</item>
       <item name="android:maxHeight">15dip</item>
       <item name="android:scaleType">centerInside</item>

</style>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 6):

As an example for implementing it as Action view, "Emanuel Moecklin" is the owner of [following Code](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/actionbarsherlock/4zD37K7vQks)

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    final Context context = actionBar.getThemedContext();
    final String[] entries = new String[] { "Entry 1", "Entry 2", "Entry 3" };
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context,
            R.layout.sherlock_spinner_item, entries);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.sherlock_spinner_dropdown_item);

    // create ICS spinner
    IcsSpinner spinner = new IcsSpinner(this, null,
            R.attr.actionDropDownStyle);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(IcsAdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Item selected: " + entries[position],
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(IcsAdapterView<?> parent) {
        }
    });

    // configure custom view
    IcsLinearLayout listNavLayout = (IcsLinearLayout) getLayoutInflater()
            .inflate(R.layout.abs__action_bar_tab_bar_view, null);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
    listNavLayout.addView(spinner, params);
    listNavLayout.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT); // <-- align the spinner to the
                                                // right

    // configure action bar
    actionBar.setCustomView(listNavLayout, new ActionBar.LayoutParams(
            Gravity.RIGHT));
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, it is impossible to move Action bar features from the left to the right. You can, however, add a `Spinner` as an [Action View](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionView) and customize it so that it looks and behaves exactly like the `Spinner` from the Action bar list navigation.

Comment: I ended up using this method. It's kind of annoying though, since you have to set the title by hand as well...

Comment: I've tried every way I know how to get a view to the right, but still don't get it to work. We are talking about the Action View's layout, correct? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22991399/align-custom-spinner-to-the-right-actionbar-compat

Answer (score 2):

**Add UI components** at the **Right** side of **Actionbar** using **ToolBar**:

Check [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html) link for more details of **ToolBar**.

Screenshot attached.

[image]

**toolbar.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    style="@style/ToolBarStyle"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/rlToolBarMain"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical">



    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

**Style** for **Application**

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/myPrimaryColor</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/myPrimaryDarkColor</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/myAccentColor</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/myTextPrimaryColor</item>
        <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>

        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/myWindowBackground</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
        <item name="spinBars">true</item>
        <item name="color">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ToolBarStyle" parent="">
        <item name="popupTheme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light</item>
        <item name="theme">@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**Include xml in activity_main.xml**

```
<include
   android:id="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"
   layout="@layout/toolbar_default"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Your **Activity** must be **extends** **AppCompatActivity**

on **onCreate** of **Activity**

```
Toolbar mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_actionbar);
setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

on **onCreateView** of **Fragment**

```
Toolbar  mToolBar = (Toolbar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar_actionbar);
RelativeLayout rlToolBarMain = (RelativeLayout)mToolBar.findViewById(R.id.rlToolBarMain);

Spinner mSpinner = new Spinner(getActivity());
String[] frags = new String[]{
                "category1",
                "category2",
                "category3",
        };
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,frags);
mSpinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
rlToolBarMain.addView(mSpinner);
```

**Done**

Answer (score 0):

Just try this ,

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        app:title="@string/app_name">

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/Method"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="right|center_vertical" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```