# How to right-align a navigation dropdown in ActionBar?

Tags: android

I've created a new project and had Eclipse create some skeleton code for an Activity with an ActionBar. I've removed the default menu that was also created (the "Settings" icon that shows on the right side).

**Problem**
Now that there's no Settings menu in the ActionBar, I want my dropdown to align to the right.
How is that possible ?

**Screenshot**
[image]

**Code Sample**

```
public class Main extends FragmentActivity implements ActionBar.OnNavigationListener
{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // Set up the action bar to show a dropdown list.
        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);

        // Set up the dropdown list navigation in the action bar.
        actionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks(
        // Specify a SpinnerAdapter to populate the dropdown list.
                new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActionBar().getThemedContext(),
                        android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                        android.R.id.text1, new String[] {
                                getString(R.string.title_section1),
                                getString(R.string.title_section2),
                                getString(R.string.title_section3), }), this);
    }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    // no settings menu
    return false;
}
}
```

Comment: how you where did this ,please can you tell me.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It is impossible to move Action bar features from the left to the
>   right. You can, however, add a Spinner as an Action View and customize
>   it so that it looks and behaves exactly like the Spinner from the
>   Action bar list navigation.

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15732152/794336

Comment: thanks! I wish Android made basic style like this easier to accomplish.